# how to configure cache response header for root path only?

Tags: nginx, webserver

i am using nginx for static files and want that all files should be cached by browser, but not index.html. Tried following config but i get cache response header for index.html also.
how can i change config?

```
server{
  location = / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   add_header 'Cache-Control' "public, max-age=3600";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the logic of `try_files $uri $uri/ ...` directive (and the whole nginx behavior) I recommend you to read [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1094257/498657) answer at ServerFault. The essential thing is

> The very important yet absolutely non-obvious thing is that an `index` directive being used with `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` can cause an internal redirect.

This is what happens with your current config. The `$uri/` argument of the `try_files` directive causes nginx to make an internal redirect from `/` to `/index.html`, and that URI in turn is processed by the `location / { ... }`, not the `location = / { ... }`! To achieve what you want you can use

```
location = /index.html {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    add_header 'Cache-Control' "public, max-age=3600";
}
```

Moreover, since the `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` is default nginx behavior, you can further simplify it to

```
location = /index.html {}
location / {
    add_header 'Cache-Control' "public, max-age=3600";
}
```